# How to Set JPG Type as The default save type in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, jpg

Is there any option to save a file only in `.jpg` file format in Photoshop CS6? Actually I don't want to take any scrolling to indicate JPG mode when I'm going to `save` or `save as` an image.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl/command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save for web. It will remember the settings so you can change quality, file type too if you want (png, gif, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the good information. So **Ctrl/command**+ **S** and **So Ctrl/command**+**Shift**+**S** in these locations are not possible to set JPG type as the default?

Comment: No, the default control/cmd + S is to save as a PSD doc   mainly. Saving for web is better than using the above command as it will output the files differently

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can set a default file type for the "save as.." It will save in the same format as it already is and if there's no layers (for example) if you do a normal "save."

**But you can set a default format for the "export as" or "quick export" in the "export" in the menu "file" on Adobe Photoshop.**

[image: export preference save for web]

Then you can select your favorite format and even the folder to save into by default if you want.

[image: save for web in png, jpg, gif by default]

Then you can use the "export" or "export as" in the export menu (or its keyboard shortcut) or even right-click on a layer or flatten layers, and see the export there too.

[image: export as quick default layers way to save in Photoshop]

---

And you can use Presets in your "save for web" too.

Comment: this is great, now if I could set a different file format than the 5 or so it lets you choose from.

Answer (score -1):

Click on Windows, New Workspace, and name your own work space. Check all the boxes for Keyboard Shortcuts, Menus, Toolbar.

Once all that is saved, try again with a new image. All JPS settings will be saved. Might need to restart Photoshop.

Answer (score -2):

This may not be anyone else's problem, but all I had to do was check the "delete cropped pixels" box at the top of the window. That's it.

Comment: What window? Be a bit more specific if possible.

Comment: See my comment to Bobb above.

Answer (score -3):

Select "Delete Cropped Pixels" in the toolbar to save as the same format as the original. This only works if there are no layers. In that case, it will automatically save as PSD, unless you choose another format.

Comment: If you make no changes to the original (bitmap) image that requires any special formatting by Photoshop then the original format will be retained. Adding any vector objects, fonts or adding layers and paths will require the image to be saved in a different format.